# How can I override Ext.Loader?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I put a copy of the `Ext.Loader` file in my `myApp\overrides` folder.

I also edited `sencha.cfg` so it is like this:

```
app.classpath=${app.dir}/app,${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/overrides
```

I also put this in my `app.js` requires:

```
requires: [
    'AMC.overrides.Loader'
]
```

Tried this too:

```
requires: [
    'overrides.Loader'
]
```

But when I build I still get this error:

> com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to find any files for C:\myworkspace\myApp\app.js::ClassRequire::overrides.Loader

Comment: Don't mess with Ext.Loader unless you feel extremely masochistic. The Land of Big Pain lies down that road.

Comment: Agree with Alex's comment. In the first place, why would you want to override it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: We localize our app using https://github.com/TigrouMeow/extjs-locale-loader. It works great when the app is not minified, so that's why I need to override Loader. What I am doing works great and is safe. So how can I get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also got into this problem, because I am using [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev)

This is the best solution I got so far:

```
/**
 * Override for Ext.Loader.getPath using Interceptor
 * @return {string} The path after the build process
 */
(function() {
    var method = Ext.Loader.getPath;
    Ext.Loader.getPath = function() {
        var path = method.apply(this, arguments);
        return my.bootstrap.assets[path] || path;
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.Loader` has a `paths` configuration that allows you to specify custom paths for each namespace.

For example if your `AMC.overrides.whatever.ClassName` paths is `/overrides/whatever/ClassName.js`, then you would need configuration like this:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    paths: {
        'AMC.overrides': scriptsRoot + '/overrides',
    }
});
```

I don't use the Sencha Builder (sench-cmd), but above works fine in the browser and it should work for the builder too.

Obviously `scriptsRoot` would have to be defined as a global in your HTML, JSP or whatever you are using to serve the application. Something like this maybe:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        scriptsRoot = '${applicationHome}/js';
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="${applicationHome}/js/loaderConfig.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${applicationHome}/js/app.js"></script>
```

And when use `requires` (or `uses`) config you should always use full name (e.g. `AMC.overrides.whatever.ClassName`).